# php domdocument or domxpath: how to extract TRs and save html

Tags: php, domdocument, domxpath

I have been struggling with this all day.

I have an html table in a string.

```
<TABLE>
  <TBODY>
    <TR CLASS=dna1>
      <TD></TD><TD></TD><TD></TD><TD></TD>
    </TR>
    <TR CLASS=dna2>
      <TD></TD><TD></TD><TD></TD><TD></TD>
    </TR>
    repeat...
```

Inside the `<TD>` are some `<DIV`> and `<SPAN>` that I need to work with.

I need to extract each `<TR>` (both classes) and save the *html* in an array where each `<TR>` is an array element.

Creating a node list array is easy enough, but how do I get the actual html?

Comment: Why do you want to save the HTML to the array? Would saving the DOMElement not be enough?

Comment: @Tomalak because I need to preserve formatting and tags.

Comment: But the DOMElement it *will* preserve all its properties...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you must save the HTML as a string, there is [DOMDocument::saveHTML](http://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.savehtml.php)

```
$elems = $xpath->query('//tr');

foreach ($elems as $elem) {
  $array[] = $doc->saveHTML($elem);
}
```

*(Note that the parameter for `saveHTML` is available as of PHP 5.3.6.)*

I'd recommend saving the nodes themselves, though, and converting them to string only shortly before you output them.

Comment: That's what I was doing wrong. I was using saveHTML(). Thanks!

Comment: See my alternative using DOMDocument only

Comment: Already up-voted, I'm way ahead of you. The OP explicitly stated DOMXPath, but *how* exactly the nodes are being selected is actually secondary for this question.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively using `DOMDocument` only:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();   
@$dom->loadHTML($html);

if($table=$dom->getElementsByTagName('table')->item(0)){

    //traverse the table and output every rows

    $rows=array();
    foreach ($table->childNodes as $row){

        $rows[]=$dom->saveHTML($row);

    }
}
```